# create Form For basic Class not Model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Lets say I have a class that generates a PDF as output. 
Different `attributes` can passed to it when initializing it.

```
 PDFGenerate.new(page: 4, user: 5, year: 2016, day: 13 ....)
```

Now I would like to create an View/Controller for that Class so that the user can simply create a PDF over the Web Applicaction. I would like to do something like that:

```
class PDFController < ActionController::Base
    def index
       @pdf_generate = PDFGenerate.new
    end

    def show
       send_data PDFGenerate.new(params).inline
    end
end
```

In my view I would like to have:

```
<%= form_for @pdf_generate do |f| %>

<%=  f.text_field :page %>
.......
```

But it is not working like this because `@pdf_generate` Is not a `Model`.
**How can I create a Form for a Basic Class like `PDFGenerate` ?** Thanks

Comment: Where is your class living?  Have you explicitly required it in your controller?  Classes in the Models directory are automatically loaded into the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not an actual model, writing a form like this isn't gonna help.
I say you should just write a basic html form and work with that.